# org-mode: go back from sparse tree to previous visibility

Tags: emacs, org-mode

After filtering my document to a sparse tree, how do I undo the filter, going back to the previous view/visibility? Because I haven't worked out how to do this out I have to make everything visible, which isn't nice in big documents. Seems like it must be obvious but I can't find the answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like it might be possible to me. In the following code I use some advice to save the outline state before generating the sparse tree, and to restore it when it is cleared via C-c C-c.

```
(setq lexical-binding t)

(let ((*outline-data* nil))
  (defun org-save-outline-state (&optional arg type)
    (setq *outline-data* (org-outline-overlay-data t)))

  (defun org-restore-outline-state (&optional arg)
    (when *outline-data*
      (org-set-outline-overlay-data *outline-data*)
      (setq *outline-data* nil))))

(advice-add 'org-sparse-tree :before 'org-save-outline-state)
(advice-add 'org-match-sparse-tree :before 'org-save-outline-state)
(advice-add 'org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c :after 'org-restore-outline-state)
```

It seems to do what you want.

Comment: `org-outline-overlay-data` and `org-set-outline-overlay-data` have been removed from Orgmode:  https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/org-mode/commit/013941de86e0f70554ecc5a87abd53562f4be897

Answer (score 13):

According to [Bastien on the org mailing list](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/44181), this isn't possible and is a long-standing wishlist item.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure you can go back to the exact previous view. But one first step is **C-c C-c** which will remove temporary highlights/overlays from the current buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't restore the previous view. I want something like winner-mode for org.

Answer (score 2):

You can create two windows using C-x 2, then switch to the other window, do the sparse tree. When you are done simply go back to the original window and press C-x 1 to close the sparse tree window.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work. It's still the same buffer, just two different views. It is possible to create a  indirect buffer (M-x make-indirect-buffer), enable org-mode in it and do the sparse tree there.

Answer (score 1):

You probably cannot go back to the same view as before.

But there are 3 steps to remove the spare tree effects:

1. `org-agenda-remove-restriction-lock` to remove the locked items'
   highlighted background.
2. `org-remove-occur-highlights` to remove the prefix's highlight.
3. `widen` to remove the restriction to the special entry, and expand to
   view the full file.