# How do I revert a sparse-tree view in org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am learning org mode, and just found out about sparse trees (C-c / t and its kin). How can I go back to the original, unsparse, view of my org document?

I found out by trial and error that TAB-cycling the top node works, is there a better way?

Comment: See a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6666862/753817

Comment: `C-u C-u TAB` runs `org-set-startup-visibility` which is a similar approach to reverting the buffer or re-running `org-mode`.

Answer (score 62):

`C-c C-c` should clear out the sparse-tree hiding and highlighting, but as far as I know, you can't just go back to the "last view" you had of it. If you want to go back to the full-view, use `Shift-Tab` to cycle all entries.

Answer (score 15):

So, it's now 2018 and (AFAIK) this feature still doesn't exist.

The best workaround I've found so far, is to create an indirect buffer (C-x 4 c) and then run org-sparse-tree in there.  The original window remains unaffected, so you keep your view, and changes to the indirect buffer will update the original buffer (and vice-versa).  When you're done, you just close the indirect buffer.

Comment: It's now 2020, and this seems like the best workaround so far.

Answer (score 9):

I usually just run the `org-mode` command which seems to get me back to square one.

Comment: This didn't seem to do anything for me. The "\\" sparse markings are still there.

Comment: This works for me (macOS; doom emacs).

Answer (score 7):

Ben K. was on the right track. Indirect buffers are one of emacs' most powerful features.

This function does what I would have expected `org-show-todo-tree` to do: create a new buffer showing undone TODO items, don't screw up my org file's tree state, and clear the unnecessary occur highlighting.

```lisp
(defun org-todo-buffer ()
  "Create new indirect buffer with sparse tree of undone TODO items"
  (interactive)
  (clone-indirect-buffer "*org TODO undone*" t)
  (org-show-todo-tree nil) ; mimics interactive usage
  (org-remove-occur-highlights)
)
```

In this new buffer you can change TODO item states which are reflected in your org file, and you can simply kill the indirect buffer when you are done with it.

Answer (score 6):

Coming to this very late, I noticed that selecting all tags then un-highlighting/un-narrowing seems to do the right thing.

```
C-c \ *
C-c C-c
```

Answer (score 5):

TAB-cycling anywhere only hides the entries highlighted by `org-sparse-tree`.

To remove the overlays, you need to actually edit the buffer.

Answer (score 3):

As you said, you can there by visibility cycling with S-TAB, but I personally don't like  visibility cycling because I'm never sure where I am in the cycle.

So I just created this simple org-agenda-custom-command that shows everything without highlighting. Just add it to your .emacs file.

```
 (setq org-agenda-custom-commands
        ; ... other commands
        `(("z"  "All" occur-tree "."
           ((org-show-entry-below t)
            (org-highlight-sparse-tree-matches nil)))))
```

There probably is a better way to do this, and the beauty of SO is someone will tell us :).

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do to work around this is to use `C-x C-v RET` (find-alternate-file) or `M-x revert-buffer`.  This works only if you don't have unsaved edits.

Comment: Shift-Tab will remove the filter without the need to reload.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the  (setq org-agenda-custom-commands.. answer works the best for me.

Use with (sorry, it wasn't obvious to me):

C-c a z