# Return to full view after `org-sparse-tree`

Tags: emacs, org-mode

1. I open `foo.org`
2. I run `org-tags-sparse-tree` to narrow the file to show only a subset of content
3. I want to go back to the *full view* of the file

How do I achieve (3) - without deleting the buffer and re-opening the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a sparse-tree view in org mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452165/how-do-i-revert-a-sparse-tree-view-in-org-mode)